# Inverting an Equation Involving Floors?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory, inequality, inverse, ceiling-and-floor-functions

How does one rewrite

$$
l = \left\lfloor\frac{10\lfloor\frac{d}{7}\rfloor+\lfloor\frac{d}{10}\rfloor(\lfloor\frac{d}{10}\rfloor+1)}{2}\right\rfloor
$$

in terms of $l$ such that the isolate variable, $d$, represents the least possible value corresponding to an input $l$ for both $l$ and $d$ are positive integers?

Thanks to Ross Millikan's response,
$$
d = \left\lfloor\frac{\sqrt{1070^2+4*7*1400l}-1070}{14}\right\rfloor
$$
has been found to be a rough approximation of the inverse of the original equation. The original equation produces the following input-output pairs in the form $(d,l)$:
$$
A(30,26), B(50,50), C(70,78), D(90,105), E(100,125)
$$
For each of these pairs, the input is the least possible value of $d$ that is mapped to its respective output of $l$. However, if you input the set of values of $l$ into the inverted equation, the following coordinate pairs in the form $(d,l)$ are produced:
$$
A'(28,26), B'(49,50), C'(70,78), D'(87,105), E'(99,125)
$$
That is, the inverted equation produces impossibly low outputs. Notice that points $C$ and $C'$ remain intact. I believe that this is because $l=70$ for these two points: 70 is divisible by both $7$ and $10$.

Say that the original equation represents the number of leaves that a growing caterpillar has eaten since its birth at day $d=0$. The caterpillar sleeps when it is not eating. Once every seventh day after its birth, first occurring at $d=7$, it awakens to consume $5$ leaves, then returns to sleep. Every tenth day after its birth, first occurring at $d=10$, it consumes one leaf for every tenth day it has been alive. Thus, at $d=7$, $l=5$, at $d=10$, $l=6$, at $d=14$, $l=11$, at $d=20$, $l=13$, and so forth. In the original equation, the factors $\lfloor\frac{d}{7}\rfloor$ and $\lfloor\frac{d}{10}\rfloor$ are used as checks to ensure that the caterpillar eats no leaves while it is sleeping; if $d$ is not a multiple of $7$ or $10$, then the caterpillar eats not even a fraction of a leaf, for it is asleep.

So how can the original equation be inverted such that passing in a value of $l$ produces an the least possible output value $d$ for which the original equation would produce the lowest possible value of $l$ that is at least the value of $l$ that was passed in to the inverted equation to begin?

Comment: You can't because $v$ is not a bijection. For, note that $v(i)=v(j)=0$ whenever $0\leqslant i,j<7$ (this is just one example).

Comment: It is confusing to change the order of the variables in the pairs between the unprimed and primed examples.  If you fix that, you will see the discrepancy is never more than 3 units, though for $d=69$ you get $l=66$, while inserting $l=66$ to the second gives $d'=61$.  This should not be surprising.  The floor functions lower $l$ relative to $d$, but not in any "nice" way.  I suggested my approach to get close, then just search.  In fact, for many $l$ values there is no $d$ that produces it because of the jumps that are caused by the floors.  Why does this surprise you?

Comment: Passing $l=150$ into the inverse equation produces $d=112$. However, $l$ is not at least $150$ until $d=119$. The idea was that the original equation be inverted such that given an input $l$, the lowest possible value of $d$ for which $l$ is at least the value passed in is returned.

Comment: I've fixed the coordinate arrangements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to start by ignoring all the floors, giving $1400l=570d+7d^2$ and use the quadratic equation to get $d=(-570+\sqrt {570^2+4\cdot 7 \cdot 1400l})/14$, where I took the plus sign because $d$ should be positive.  This will give a lower bound for $d$.  Now just count upward until you find what you like.  For example, if $l=100$, my equation gives $d=106.4511$.  Rounding up to $107$ and inserting the floors gives $l=92$.  Counting up, we find $(d=109, l=92), (d=110,l=103)$ as solutions to your original equation.  Which of these do you consider best?

Comment: Of any set of solutions for l = c, the solution for which d is the least is required.

Comment: I am having an issue with the computation you used to verify the solution (d = 126, l = 96) when passing the values back into the original equation with floors. If I pass d = 126 into the original equation as you suggest, the first term becomes 5 * floor(126/7), becomes 5 * floor(18), becomes 5 * 18, becomes 90. Evaluating the second term, floor(126/10) becomes floor(12.6), becomes 12. Adding 1 for the second factor in the second term, we get 13. Thus, the second term becomes 12 * 13, becomes 156. Summing the terms produces 246. Dividing by two and flooring produces the integer 123, not 96.

Comment: @CharlesVentin: I found an error in the calculation.  It now checks, and requires fewer steps up.  For a given $l$, there may not be any $d$ that produces it, as we see here.

Comment: I realized that I had an error in recording the original equation: the coefficient of the first term was supposed to be $10$, not $5$. Even after the adjustment to the inverse equation, though, the coordinate pars don't align. I've edited the question to highlight the problem.